# How do I make a sql job step quit reporting failure

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-job

I have a sql job step

like this

```
Declare 
@Result varchar(255)

exec myprocedure
@Result = @Result output
```

What I want to do:
if @Result = 'Error' then mark the job as failed, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to the end of your script:

```
if @Result = 'Error'
    raiserror('The stored procedure returned an error',16,1)
```

And make sure that on the "Advanced" tab of the step properties, the "on failure action" is set to "Quit the job reporting failure"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try Catch

```
Begin Try
   exec myprocedure
   @Result = @Result output
End Try

Begin Catch
   /*Do whatever you want here*/
End Catch
```