# Stored Procedure Return Value to Fail SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value, sql-server-agent

I have a stored procedure which is the first step in an SQL Job. The SP compares dates in 2 tables, if they equal then the SQL job can continue, but if they are not I need to return value from the SP that causes the SQL Job to trigger it's on failure action.

What is the best way to do this? Is it with an RAISERROR statement or just return a value like -99?

Seems such an obvious question, but I've never thought about it before until now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a sql job step quit reporting failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206394/how-do-i-make-a-sql-job-step-quit-reporting-failure)

Comment: In general: use try/catch exceptions in preference to error codes  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever way you want. You can use a try/catch and raiserror. That can allow you to write the error to the event log as well if desired.

Typically, I'd just use an IF statement that does a return and then proceed with the rest of the code otherwise.

I think it's a matter of preference/requirements, though. Either will get the job done.

Comment: thanks for the reply. When you say you'd use an IF statement that does a return. What would you return from the SP an error or just a value like -999?

Comment: It depends. You can use RETURN to return a value or use an output parameter. Either works. Again, I think it's a matter of preference. As long as you're consistent with your methodology, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best practice approaches are:

1. a function that returns a bit 1/0 (True/False)
2. stored proc output parameter

Proc return values are meant to be used to test the success or failure of the proc itself, usually 0 for success and some other error number when there is an error